# How to set a lot of values to UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uipickerview

I have a pickerview with 2 rows and I need to fill them automatically. First row: numbers from 150 to 210 and second row: from 40 to 130. Can anyone help me with this?

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *ar1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"150", @"151", @"152", nil];
    self.array1 = ar1;
    [ar1 release];

    NSArray *ar2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"40", @"41", @"42", nil];
    self.array2 = ar2;
    [ar2 release];

        [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoulf use `for` loop for that. The code:

```
NSArray *ar1 = [NSArray array];
for (int i = 150; i <= 210; i++)
    ar1 = [ar1 arrayByAddingObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
[ar1 retain];
self.array1 = ar1;

NSArray *ar2 = [NSArray array];
for (int j = 40; j <= 130; j++)
    ar2 = [ar2 arrayByAddingObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
[ar2 retain];
self.array2 = ar2;
```

---

**EDIT:** It will be better when you'll use `NSMutableArray` instead.

```
NSArray *ar1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 150; i <= 210; i++)
    [ar1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
self.array1 = ar1;

NSArray *ar2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int j = 40; j <= 130; j++)
    [ar2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
self.array2 = ar2;
```

Comment: when I use your code, app crashes and log gives me: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Comment: 2011-05-15 14:32:40.874 Laskurit[3623:207] -[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b58580
2011-05-15 14:32:40.937 Laskurit[3623:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b58580'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: This is because you use `isEQualToString` with a number. I updated my code so that your error should disappear.

Comment: This is highly inefficient. You're creating hundreds of temporary NSArray objects this way, you should use NSMutableArray instead, as suggested by jamihash. Also, ar1 and ar2 are leaked, because of the additional retain. They are already retained by the property setter (unless the property is declared as assign, which wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: @omz: OK, you're right. @Pavel: It'll be better when you use my new code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSMutableArray and then in a 'for loop' create the strings and add them to the array using the addObject method.